# Как сделать картинку меняющую , при наведении , зажатии , отжатии , отведении?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
 <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="Castle" >
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/passClose.png" />

       
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseDirectlyOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/passOpen.png" />

            </Trigger>
          
            
        </Style.Triggers>

       
    </Style>
```

1. У меня картинка при не наведённой мышки на неё выглядит вот так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. При наведённой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. При зажатой мышки на картинку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. При отжатой мышки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как сделать так, что бы в 1 случаи замок был закрыт, и все остальные пункты также работали, как на скринах ?**

Менять картинки местами пробовал.

Comment: Вы ведь делаете уже подобное, меняете триггером нужные значения, в чем проблема то? И да, советую вам очень сильно перейти на векторную графику!

Comment: **<Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="Castle" >
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/passClose.png" />


            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/passOpen.png"  />

                </Trigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>**

В том что , если я так напишу, то при зажатии мышки замок закрывается, а должен быть открытым.

Comment: Ну а триггер на зажатие где? И почему вы вообще делаете стиль для картинки, когда вам нужна кнопка?

Comment: Там кнопка, картинка на кнопку накинута.

Comment: А стиль у вас для чего? `TargetType="Image"` Вот вам нужно сейчас обработать "зажатие", это событие кнопки, или сейчас вы обрабатываете события появления курсора над объектом, объект картинка, то есть если навестись на кнопку, то значит и картинку менять не надо, так что ли? По вашей логике да, ибо вы непойми зачем меняете контент, а не саму кнопку...

Comment: На скорую руку набросал то, что вам [нужно](https://pastebin.com/1EgGNLa7), простая кнопка, два события, не более. [Результат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhBhw.gif).